# Allow import from the original module only

Tags: python, lint, pre-commit-hook

Suppose I have three modules:

`a.py`

```py
class A: ...
```

`b.py`

```py
from a import A
```

`c.py`

```py
from b import A
```

Is there some tool that flags the import in `c.py`, as it is a re-import from the original module?

Comment: seeking recommendations for tools is off topic on stackoverflow as it tends to invite spammy, advertisery responses

Comment: @AnthonySottile, I'm not asking for a specific recommendation but rather about the general existence of such tools. Despite rather extensive searching I could not find any.

Comment: then trivially the answer is "yes" but that's also not a useful question and answer